# Bonding in the primary structure of a protein

Tags: protein-structure

My textbook says:

> The amino group of an amino acid reacts with the carbonyl group of another amino acid at the end of a polypeptide chain. This condensation reaction forms a peptide bond. ... The precise sequence of amino acids in a polypeptide chain is the primary structure of the protein.

Later, it states that

> The primary structure of a protein is established by covalent bonds ...

Is the primary structure of a protein governed by covalent bonds or peptide bonds? Are peptide bonds a type of covalent bond?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peptide bonds (also called amide bonds) are definitely covalent bonds.
This is also mentioned in the first line of wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptide_bond

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Lots of words for the same thing.

Covalent bonds are any bonds where electrons are shared. Polyamide bonds, peptide bond etc.